# Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema' on mac

Tags: angular, macos, npm, angular-cli

On my mac i installed angular-cli with

```
brew install angular-cli
```

but when i run `ng g service test` i get this error:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:6:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

but when i run npm start it works fine.

any idea how can i fix this?

my versions are:
node v8.9.3
npm v5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start the command prompt as a administrator and run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli -g --save
```

Comment: when i run `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli -g --save` i get this error `Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli` how can i fix it?

Comment: I removed `/usr/local/bin/ng` and `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli` manually and it works now.